# fill in the multidimensional array with missing keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following multidimensional array. I had to create keys the way it looks to group them accordingly.

```
Array
(
    [Oranges] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Oranges
            [l.VA123] => 17
            [l.MA123] => 12
            [l.GA123] => 9
            [l.CT123] => 5
        )

    [Apple] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Apple
            [l.CA123] => 13
        )

    [Grapes] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Grapes
            [l.WI123] => 8
            [l.FL123] => 5
        )
)
```

However, I need all the subarrays to have the same keys. Missing ones should be filled with a value of 0. The final array should be like below so that all subarrays have equal length.

```
    Array
(
    [Oranges] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Oranges
            [l.VA123] => 17
            [l.MA123] => 12
            [l.GA123] => 9
            [l.CT123] => 5
            [l.CA123] => 0
            [l.WI123] => 0
            [l.FL123] => 0
        )

    [Apple] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Apple
            [l.CA123] => 13
            [l.WI123] => 0
            [l.FL123] => 0
            [l.VA123] => 0
            [l.MA123] => 0
            [l.GA123] => 0
            [l.CT123] => 0
        )

    [Grapes] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Grapes
            [l.WI123] => 8
            [l.FL123] => 5
            [l.CA123] => 0
            [l.VA123] => 0
            [l.MA123] => 0
            [l.GA123] => 0
            [l.CT123] => 0
        )
)
```

Comment: `Name` or `Gene` key in subarrays?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a simple `+` operator. As from [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php):

> The + operator returns the right-hand array appended to the left-hand array; for keys that exist in both arrays, the elements from the left-hand array will be used, and the matching elements from the right-hand array will be ignored.

```
$items = Array
(
    'Oranges' => Array
        (
            'Name' => 'Oranges',
            'l.VA123' => 17,
            'l.MA123' => 12,
            'l.GA123' => 9,
            'l.CT123' => 5,
        ),

    'Apple' => Array
        (
            'Name' => 'Apple',
            'l.CA123' => 13,
        ),

    'Grapes' => Array
        (
            'Name' => 'Grapes',
            'l.WI123' => 8,
            'l.FL123' => 5,
        ),
);

// static keys
$keys = [
    'l.VA123' => 0,
    'l.MA123' => 0,
    'l.GA123' => 0,
    'l.CT123' => 0,
    'l.CA123' => 0,
    'l.WI123' => 0,
    'l.FL123' => 0,
];


// keys generated from source array, tricky approach
$keys = array_fill_keys(
    // here we merge all elements of `$items` into one array
    // as keys are repeated - you definitely got all keys that
    // can be in `$items`, `array_keys` will give you these keys
    // `array_fill_keys` will create array where key is what you need
    // and value is 0.
    array_keys(call_user_func_array('array_merge', $items)),
    0
);

// keys generated from source array, SIMPLE approach
$keys = [];
foreach ($items as $item) {
    foreach ($item as $k => $v) {
        if ($k != 'Name') {
            $keys[$k] = 0;
        }
    }
}

foreach ($items as &$item) {
    $item = $item + $keys;
}
print_r($items);
```

Comment: I updated the Q. It is not `Name`. The new array needs to have the missing keys with values 0

Comment: I changed key from `Gene` to `Name`, but it doesn't matter. My answer stays the same.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I don't want to create the new keys manually. Is there a way I can create the list keys from the multidimensional array ?

Comment: Also added simple approach which doesn't require much comments)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php, right before first `warning` block

Answer (score 2):

Probably someone can come up with something more efficient, but without a list of keys that you want, I think you'll need to take a couple of passes of the array:

```
<?php
$fruits = [
    "Oranges"=>["Name"=>"Oranges", "l.VA123"=>17, "l.MA123"=>12, "1.GA123"=>9, "1.CT123"=>5],
    "Apple"=>["Name"=>"Apple", "1.CA123"=>13],
    "Grapes"=>["Name"=>"Grapes", "1.WI123"=>8, "1.FL123"=>5]
];
$keys = [];
foreach ($fruits as $fruit) {
    unset($fruit["Name"]);
    $keys = array_merge($keys, array_keys($fruit));
}
$keys = array_fill_keys(array_unique($keys), 0);

foreach ($fruits as &$fruit) {
    $fruit = array_merge($keys, $fruit);
}
print_r($fruits);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since all keys and default values are "known", create an associative array, use a `foreach()` and modify the rows by reference, and use the union-assignment (combined) operator.  This will allow the original values to overwrite the default values.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/iCIpG))

```
$keys = [
    'l.VA123' => 0,
    'l.MA123' => 0,
    'l.GA123' => 0,
    'l.CT123' => 0,
    'l.CA123' => 0,
    'l.WI123' => 0,
    'l.FL123' => 0,
];

foreach ($items as &$row) {
    $row += $keys;
}
var_export($items);
```

---

If you want the keys to be consistently positioned, then use `array_replace()` or `array_merge()` instead of the union assignment operator.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/nJKka))

```
foreach ($items as &$row) {
    $row = array_replace($keys, $row);
}
```